# Unable to fetch data and React is not giving any error messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';

const API = `http://accountmanagement.ng.bluemix.net/v1/accounts/${accountGuid}/traits`;

class GetMFAValidation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: '' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>HOLA, I AM ${accountGuid}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
        console.log('data -->', data);
        this.setState({ data });
      });
  }
}

GetMFAValidation.propTypes = {
  accountGuid: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default compose(
  connect(
    store => ({ accountGuid: store.global.accountGuid }),
    translate(),
  ),
)(GetMFAValidation);
```

And I am calling it in another component like:

`import GetMFAValidation from "../path"`
And `<GetMFAValidation />`

The app crashes but I am not receiving any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your **API** string has a variable in it:

```
const API = `http://accountmanagement.ng.bluemix.net/v1/accounts/${accountGuid}/traits`;
```

...but **accountGuid** is not accessible here.

You could use a function instead:

```
const getAPIUrl = (accountGuid) => 
  `http://accountmanagement.ng.bluemix.net/v1/accounts/${accountGuid}/traits`;
```

And then pass in the **accountGuid** from props when used:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const APIUrl = getAPIUrl(this.props.accountGuid)
  fetch(APIUrl).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
    console.log('data -->', data);
    this.setState({ data });
  });
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

in your fetch methode, try to add a catch after then, and print the error, if it is because of the fetch, your program will still work, and you will get the error

```
fetch(API).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
    console.log('data -->', data);
    this.setState({ data });
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```